# NServiceBus 5 - Get handlers mapping

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus5

I have a NServiceBus project and it maps objects in my assemblies that implement `IHandleMessage<Type>`.

I'm wondering if there is any way to get a list of all mappings of Classes to their Handlers?

Comment: I'm curious, what would you be using that unified list for?

Comment: Checkout [ServiceInsight](http://docs.particular.net/serviceinsight/getting-started-overview), (though this is more around runtime mappings)

Comment: @UdiDahan I have developed a library that when copied to an NServiceBus project starts itself and with the Unit Of Work pattern tracks and keeps statistics on what the system is doing - which messages are passed in, how many times, how long - I started it so I could keep track on what's being called in my system so I can know what I need to debug in code. Now what I'm trying to do is add something to this tool that will help me know if there are any messages coming in that has no Handlers in code for them.

Comment: It is considered an error - see: http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/handlers/#what-happens-when-there-are-no-handlers-for-a-message

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be looking for the MessageHandlerRegistry
https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/blob/463f464c25bd71c7d6dbb522484e452ea47214c1/src/NServiceBus.Core/Unicast/IMessageHandlerRegistry.cs

I use it in my project to dispatch events retrieved from EventStore like so: https://github.com/volak/Aggregates.NET/blob/master/src/Aggregates.NET.Consumer/NServicebusDispatcher.cs

Looks like this class is going away in 6.0 though - so that might be worth knowing.